# Catch alert error in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My shell script:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Fail to reload services."
fi
```

Can't catch the error while service restart alert like:

```
[ALERT] 104/005618 (6110) : Starting frontend tinasay: cannot bind socket
```

How can I catch that alert?

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the stderr and use regular expressions:

```
output=$(sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload 2>&1)
if [[ $output =~ "ALERT" ]]; then
  echo "Fail to reload services."
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Error messages are normally written to file descriptor 2, aka standard error. They can be redirected like this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload 2> /some/log/file.log
```

This will overwrite the file and any existing contents will be lost. Instead you could also redirect the error output in append mode:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload 2>> /some/log/file.log
```

Which will append new messages after old ones.

You also don't need to check `$?` as you do, in fact it's a classic useless use. Do this instead:

```
if ! sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload 2>> /some/log/file.log ; then
    echo "Fail to reload services."
fi
```

If the return code is not 0 then the "Fail" message will be printed.

Comment: I tried: 

if ! sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy reload 2>> /some/log/file.log ; then
    echo "Fail to reload services."
fi

then haproxy reload failed, it didn't echo fail msg, so I tried to remove !, it echoed. Weird thing it's that now the normal reload still trigger the echo fail msg :(

Comment: @timy: `!` is "not" and reverses the sense of the check. Does the return code from `sudo` reflect the return code from `haproxy`? If not your original code would also not work.